# Permanent gravatar in views for a specific admin user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gravatar

To implement a gravatar for an instance of user is `<%= gravatar_for @user %>`.

What if I wanted to specify another user, an admin user, who would have a permanent gravatar in the views of all regular users. How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to either pull the admin user out of the database and use `gravatar_for(@admin_user)` or just hardcode the gravatar URL into an `image_tag`.

Do the latter if you can get away with it.

Comment: thank you Jonny, hardcoding it did work. Could you shed some light on any security issues with it? I've made a helper and hardcoded the e-mail address for the admin user.

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't used whatever gravatar gem you're using. But if it's just based on email I'm guessing the worst that could happen is that someone could get the admin's email address.